# Arduino/Genuino not in board list

Tags: arduino-ide

I've downloaded the Arduino IDE and the Genuino isn't in the list of boards. I'm running Rasbian and used the command line to install.

Comment: Which version of the IDE? A lot of Arduino boards are branded Genuino (after the fiasco of the dispute over the "Arduino" name). It could be a Genuino Uno, or Genuino Nano, or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Genuino" is just a name, not an identifier. Pick the equivalent Arduino board from the list.